# Rank SQL Query Results - Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using a PostgreSQL db and I've got the following query that searches my customer database and does so successfully:

```
SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE ((("customers"."first_name" IN ('John', 'Doe') OR "customers"."last_name" IN ('John', 'Doe')) OR "customers"."email" IN ('John', 'Doe')) OR "customers"."main_phone" IN ('John', 'Doe'))
```

The equivalent Rails query is:

```
array = ["John","Doe","111-111-1111"]

Customer.where(first_name: array).or(customers.where(last_name: array)).or(customers.where(email: array)).or(customers.where(main_phone: array))
```

This works fine, however I am wanting to rank the results. For example, if record # 1 matches for both first and last name, I want that record to display at the top of my results. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you should use sphinx, elastic search, or any other tool that allows you to do full text search and rank results (even postgresql).

But a possible naive ranking workaround can be built from the database by adding a simple match_rank for each record with the sum of fields that matched, and then ordering by that field. Something like the following:

```
array = ["John","Doe","111-111-1111"]
wrappped_array = "(" + array.map { |v| "'#{v}'" }.join(',') + ")"

Customer.select("customers.*, 
  ((CASE WHEN first_name in #{wrappend_array} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE WHEN last_name in #{wrappend_array} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE WHEN email in #{wrappend_array} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE WHEN main_phone in #{wrappend_array} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as match_rank").
where(first_name: array).
  or(customers.where(last_name: array)).
  or(customers.where(email: array)).
  or(customers.where(main_phone: array)).
  order(match_rank: :desc)
```